# Indentation error in for loop

Tags: python

The problem is:

> Finish the function sum_of_over_fives that loops over number_list and adds to the total only the numbers greater than 5. Then it should return the total.

```
def sum_of_over_fives(number_list):
       total = 0
       for number in number_list:
           number >5
             total += number
       return total
```

I get an indent error for "number >5" line but I have this gut feeling that the line is wrong.

Comment: Does the indentation look correct to you? If so, why? What are you expecting to happen with `number > 5`?

Comment: I tried indenting different ways the main error is " IndentationError: expected an indented block.

Comment: Stephen - I had tried  using 'if' as well I still get the indentation error.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use the built-ins `filter` and `sum`:

```
total = sum(filter(lambda x: x > 5, number_list))
```

Comment: If he turned that in for his assignment, the prof would know he got it here.

Comment: Well but this is how you solve the problem in Python. The OP's code is C-style, not Python.

Comment: @a_guest The OP's question is presumably why they have a syntax error. You have not answered that question, but rather provided a one-liner.

Comment: @Mitch My "one-liner" produces the desired result and does not raise an indentation error so I'd say I answered it quite certainly.

Comment: @a_guest I suppose we'll agree to disagree. I find it to be a low-quality answer to a low-quality question that should be closed.

Comment: @StephenRauch No I don't agree, this is not how you teach Python. Python is all about "batteries included" and so you should use it. There is no point in programming C in Python really.

Comment: @a_guest Suppose Python is my first language. What do you think I learn first - raw loop control flow, or built-in function abstractions? Come on.

Comment: @Mitch If someone's not managing to do something in a bad way I won't help him doing so but instead show a better alternative. Everything else is quite narrow minded i.m.o. Regarding teaching Python: _loops_ are abstract concepts, not specific to a programming language, and so you can teach those concepts independently of the language. I also don't see how `sum` or `filter` are "abstractions"; `sum(some_list)` is quite naturally doing what it's saying. Also there are plenty of cases where `for` loops are useful in Python so it's much better to teach it using such examples not redundant ones.

Comment: Since there is no Teacher involved (I am learning alone) no worries. Your code worked. Now I will study it and make sure that I really understand the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Mitch and @StephenRauch, your logic is fine, the only problem is with your indentation and the `number > 5` which should be an [if statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html).

According to the PEP 8 documentation, you must make sure that the [indentation of your function body is 4](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) ,  at the moment, it is 8.

Then the only thing left will be to put the `if` and the `:` to go with the `number > 5`. Here is your final code with the corrected indentations and the correct `if` statement:

```
def sum_of_over_fives(number_list):
    total = 0
    for number in number_list:
        if number > 5:
            total += number
    return total

print(sum_of_over_fives([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]))
>>> 
13
```

But like @a_guest said, there is a better way of doing what you are trying to do.

I hope that help :).

Comment: @ Tshilidzi Mudau I appreciate your response. Thank you for your explanation.